# How can I bypass the self-signed certificate verification when using the wss protocol with emscripten/websocket.h?

Tags: websocket, webassembly, emscripten

Client:

```
   // The IP address and port will be provided by user
   char url[256];
   snprintf(url, sizeof(url), "wss://%s:%d/", addr, port);
   url[sizeof(url)-1]=0;
   ...
   EMSCRIPTEN_WEBSOCKET_T socket = emscripten_websocket_new(&attr);
```

And I use `openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out self.pem -keyout self.pem` to generate self-signed certificate

Server:

```
    ssl = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
    //SSL_set_verify(ssl, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);

    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);
    ret = SSL_accept(ssl);
    if(ret < 0){
        ERR_load_ERR_strings();
        ERR_load_crypto_strings(); 
        unsigned long ulErr = ERR_get_error(); 
        char szErrMsg[1024] = {0};
        char *pTmp = NULL;
        pTmp = ERR_error_string(ulErr,szErrMsg); 
        printf("[*] Error-> %s\n",pTmp);
    }
```

And then print the error `Error-> error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown`

I found a lot of information showing that it is necessary to bypass the verification of the self-signed certificate on the client side.

But my client side Use `emscripten/websocket.h`, I don't know how to code it.
I need to use the sock variable of websocket, is there any other way that will work？

I try `//SSL_set_verify(ssl, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);` on the server side. But it can't take effect